# Return Seperate PHP Script Within HTML

Tags: php, html

I have a "print.php" script that basically fetches data from MySQL and creates a tiny pretty HTML table.

```
echo "
    <table cellpadding=\"2\" cellspacing=\"2\" border=\"0\" width=\"10%\">
        <tr bgcolor=\"#666666\">
            <td colspan=\"2\" align=\"center\"><b><font color=\"#FFFFFF\">" . $table[0] . "</font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Score</td>
        </tr>";
echo "<tr";

    if ($i % 2 == 0)
        echo " bgcolor=\"#CCCCCC\"";

    echo ">
        <td>" . $col['player'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $col['score'] . "</td>
    </tr>";
```

I want this table to appear in my index.html, But its in a separate php script.

I want to keep the php script separate from the HTML because the script is not only a tad large, but it has my SQL information in it to which I don't want in the plain HTML.

Is there a way to fetch this echo in my php script from my html page?

Comment: Few ways to do so: 1) iframe ; 2) use AJAX to load the contents into the place you want, e.g. a DIV

Comment: i m not sure but you can use require_once "print.php" in your html file where you want to display that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**
Use an iframe. Works even if JavaScript is turned off.

```
<iframe src="print.php"></iframe>
```

**Option 2:** Use AJAX (with jQuery).

[Download jQuery here.](http://jquery.com)

Include it in your `index.html`, preferably in your `head` tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>
```

Add this code where you want `print.php` to be included.

```
<div id="container"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#container").load("print.php");
    });
</script>
```

**Option 3:** Go the PHP route. May break other code since you need to rename the index file.

Rename your `index.html` to `index.php` and use this code:

```
<?php include("print.php"); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  Beautiful answer.
 
-The iframe solution worked, most simplest and quickest solution. Not as clean looking though.   
-AJAX, which I was already conveniently using and didn't realize it would work that way, requires the extra code but looks great.   
-And the include php was a suggestion a friend made, but I depended on the .html. It works otherwise.

Comment: @AnthonyBarranco You can always style the iframe using CSS so it doesn't show if you don't think it's clean enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call to the `print.php` from the your current page and fetch the data and show them.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "print.php"
}).done(function( html ) {
  $("#results").append(html); //results is the div id
});
```

You will have to get the basic jQuery knowledge for this.

Else you can use .load method which is also a AJAX method.

```
<div id="results"></div>

$("#results").load("print.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX Javascript to do that.

[**Documentation And Examples**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX)